# SharePoint Search Result Source (Custom Content Type)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, search-results, sharepoint-search

I am working on SharePoint 2019 where I have created custom content type. This content type includes site columns. When I create Search Result Source and include this my custom content source and path as current site collection. It always return zero result.

But when I create same kind of Search Result Source with Task content type it return correct result.

I have run full crawl again. My search have every 5 minute incremental crawl. I have reset index search service. I have reset index list but it never return zero result. Let me know what I am doing wrong.

[image]

Comment: Can you please add the search query you are using to your question?

Comment: I am just creating Result Source in Site Settings where are I try to Test result it return only zero records

Comment: Ok I come to some point. what I did is create **another content type with Parent content type as Item Content Type**  Now this content type yield results correctly. So I come to the conclusion that Parent content type should be item content type. But Kindly somebody can explain why is it so? Appreciate in advance

Comment: To reproduce this issue, could you share your steps? some screenshots will be better.